# non multiplications with numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.einsum seems to deal only with multiplication. What happens if I want to do the equivalent of:

```
np.array([x[i,:]-j*t[:,i]+u[i]*v[i,:] for i,j in enumerate(y)])
```

for x[N,n], y[N], t[n,N], u[N], v[N,n], N>n>0. Is there a syntax similar to:

```
np.einsum('ij,i,ji,i,ij->ij',x,y,t,u,v,operations=‘-,*,+,*‘)
```

? However it would not be an Einstein convention anymore...

Comment: Nothing using `einsum` or related notation to solve this.  If you ask a new question, make sure it's [mcve]

Comment: The `einsum` recommendation in your previous question was too strong.  Learn to use the broadcasting of your accepted answer first.  Replace the `j` with `y[i]` to show more clearly that your terms follow the broadcastable format of that answer.

Comment: ah, ok: I suppose I could have used here a syntax similar to my accepted previous question. Indeed, I was curious to use numpy.einsum and nothing else, so I didn't take a good example. sorry